# How to freeze a Solana nfts with React?

Tags: web3.js, nft

I did a lot of research on this subject but could not reach a conclusion. What I want to do is this; I list and display the NFTs in my user's wallet using a specific collectionKey (my own collectionKey). From here, the user will select an NFT and perform the freezing process. This may or may not be for a certain period of time. The user will select and confirm the freezing process and I will give him a special reward (like points) from my system. How do I do this? How can I find a library/framework code sample or how to do it for React?

Comment: Hey there, in order to achieve this goal you would need to freeze his token account using the the FreezeAccount instruction. To thaw the token account you will need to use the ThawAccount instruction.

Comment: Yes, I have information about this. However, when I examined the developer documentation, I could not find anything. You see, I need help with the code. Thanks

Comment: Freeze Account Instruction
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/instructions/freezeAccount.ts
and
Thaw Account Instruction
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/instructions/thawAccount.ts
You need to import this 2 instructions.

Answer (score 2):

in order to freeze the token account and thaw the token account you need to import this instructions **createFreezeAccountInstruction** and **createThawAccountInstruction** from **@solana/spl-token**

```
createFreezeAccountInstruction(
          tokenAccount,//Account to freeze
          mint,//Mint account
          payer.publicKey//Mint freeze authority
        )

createThawAccountInstruction(
          tokenAccount,//Account to freeze
          mint,//Mint account
          payer.publicKey//Mint freeze authority
        )
```

Example:

```
(async () => {
  const tokenAccount = new PublicKey('token id');
  try {
      let tx = new Transaction().add(
        createFreezeAccountInstruction(
          tokenAccount,
          mint,
          payer.publicKey
        )
      )    
      //sign tx
      let txhash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [keypair]);
      console.log(txhash)
  } catch(e) {
      console.error(`Oops, something went wrong: ${e}`)
  }
})();
```

Comment: I think I wrote the code. However, I get the "Owner does not match" error. However, all the information I have given here is correct. Could there be another reason why I'm experiencing this?

Comment: MINT: EQTXXd12kB4QjNupxAJg9fhYVE2wMM9Rvc9EgPopsbN TOKEN_ACCOUNT: 9iYcdXhFh5jTj4PKZpWXhixbMNfZkfLJm9XWZso2jaXb OWNER: 47F47sC2NVyoMGYubT2VkMay3FSJaFbhnYNXew4iRWLu

Comment: These come dynamically. I use provider for Phantom wallet and Solana. The error I get in Phantom is as above. "Owner does not match"

Comment: From what i checked the mint is :
EQTXXd12kB4QjNupxAJg9fhYVE2wMM9Rvc9EgPopsbN 
token acc: 9iYcdXhFh5jTj4PKZpWXhixbMNfZkfLJm9XWZso2jaXb 

Mint/freeze Auth: 47mvLdPJe5EEXGtksYw6fNErP5GzogjSq1u6LJCKe9yP

Comment: I shared the code I tried with you.

Comment: the mint freeze authority needs to be the signer of the transaction.

Comment: Yes, that's what this code is for, I send it to the wallet like this to confirm the transaction (Phantom): const signature = await wallet.signTransaction(tx); You can see the full code below

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong?

```
'use client';
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { PublicKey, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { createFreezeAccountInstruction } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { WalletMultiButton } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';

function Page() {
 const wallet = useWallet();
 const { connection } = useConnection();

 const freezeUserWalletNFT = async () => {
  const tx = new Transaction();
  const account = new PublicKey('9iYcdXhFh5jTj4PKZpWXhixbMNfZkfLJm9XWZso2jaXb');
  const mint = new PublicKey('EQTXXd12kB4QjNupxAJg9fhYVE2wMM9Rvc9EgPopsbN');
  const payer = wallet.publicKey;
  const authority = new PublicKey('47mvLdPJe5EEXGtksYw6fNErP5GzogjSq1u6LJCKe9yP');
  tx.add(createFreezeAccountInstruction(account, mint, authority));
  tx.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('max')).blockhash;
  tx.feePayer = payer;
  const signature = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
  const result = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signature.serialize());
  console.log('Transaction result:', result);
 };

 return (
  <div className='w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-12 gap-12'>
   <button onClick={freezeUserWalletNFT}>Freeze Wallet NFT</button>
   <WalletMultiButton>{wallet.connected ? wallet.publicKey?.toBase58() : <button onClick={wallet.connect}>Connect Wallet</button>}</WalletMultiButton>
  </div>
 );
}

export default Page;
```